# Sides of tags show through error message

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

I accidentally clicked downvote on a question and observed this:

> [image]

This bug is unique to GameDev, due to having triangles on the side of tags here:

> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed and will go out in `rev. 1340`.